# Rate Limiting Solution

Tags: facebook, api, rate, limiting

I am developing a software application that uses the Facebook API to conduct searches on open posts etc.

The issue I am trying to get my head around is rate limiting imposed by the Facebook API.

All the other tools that do similar things to mine are managed services, not stand alone software applications. So I assume customers that subscribe to the service are throttled globally from within the managed service.

My issue is that my product is a stand alone software application.

So if I sell 100 software licences and all 100 people try and use it at the same time the application could grind to a halt as the Facebook API will rate limit them.

The application will use the same Application ID; as far as I know I have to.

Is there aby solution to this problem?

Comment: With just 100 people I think you might not be able to hit the rate limit, are you sure you will be going higher than (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day)

Comment: Hi Anvesh, my application looks for statistic based on keywords contained in Search Groups. So a buyer of the software could concievably have 100 search groups with 100 keywords in each search group.

Answer (score 1):

As you are planning to build application that you consider would just exceed the starting threshold, you may do what the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) suggest, quoting from there

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

Comment: Thanks again Anvesh. So is that 100 million api calls per day? Also is the rate 600 calls in 600 seconds? I have read this before but noone seems sure.

Comment: I also read about that, but most of the posts in which this was mentioned are very old, and judging by the fast changes on the Facebook API it will be safe to assume that the rate limit has now been changed to what their Platform Policy states

Comment: Thanks Anvesh. Now I need to work out the same for the other APIs I am using! ;-)